# 999 acknowledgement AK902 value

Tags: edi, x12

I have generated 999 acknowledgement file from a claim (837) file. In the 999,AK9 segment says "~AK9*A*1*2*2~". I am using a third-party tool to generate the 999 file. In the claim file, we have two transaction set. But AK902 says "1". can somebody help me to understand the value of AK902. If I generate with another tool that is generating "~AK9*A*2*2*2~"

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my question [here](http://www.x12.org/examples/005010X231/response-to-functional-group-containing-3-837s/). This says ~AK9*A*2*2*2~ is right.

Comment: If this was the best answer for you, you may want to mark it as correct (helps filters on searches)